# (Standalone) Software for plotting graphs of large amounts of data and allowing you to scroll/zoom

Tags: data-visualization

I've got some temporal data taken from a data logger that I'm trying to plot in a graphical form (as a line graph). Because it's a large amount of data, plotting it one one big graph (e.g. in Excel) makes it difficult to explore the visualised data as you can't really zoom in and scroll through the data. What I'm looking for is some standalone software that can plot the data as a line graph, but also allow the user to easily scroll through the graph along the horizontal (time) axis and be able to zoom that axis in and out. Ideally, the software would be free and be GUI driven. Does anyone know of any such software?

Thanks,

Comment: You may find some of the suggestions at this link helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890434/javascript-library-for-drawing-graphs-over-timelines-zoomable-and-selectable

Comment: Thanks, although these are software libraries and I was looking for standalone software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much searching, I have found exactly the software I am looking for:

http://www.datplot.com/

Simple, GUI-driven software that allows you to import raw data and plot graphs, with dynamic scroll and zoom.

Comment: I'm looking for a Mac OS alternative. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

**A survey of interactive plotting software with a 10 million point scatter plot benchmark on Ubuntu 18.10**

I have published this survey at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854515/large-plot-20-million-samples-gigabytes-of-data/55967461#55967461

Here is a copy of the summary of results:

Does it handle 10 million points:

```
VisIt       Yes
Paraview    Barely
Mayavi      Yes
gnuplot     Barely on non-interactive mode.
matplotlib  No
```

Does it have a lot of features:

```
VisIt       Yes, 2D and 3D, focus on interactive.
Paraview    Same as above.
Mayavi      3D only, good interactive and scripting support, but more limited features.
gnuplot     Lots of features, but limited in interactive mode.
matplotlib  Same as above.
```

Does the GUI feel good:

```
VisIt       No
Paraview    Very
Mayavi      OK
gnuplot     OK
matplotlib  OK
```

Answer (score 1):

[Gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/index.html) is free, open source and highly versatile and what I use and I think it will meet your needs. You can point and click with the mouse to zoom in and out on any part of a graph, and you can even write a script to scroll through the data as if watching a film.

Comment: Interesting.  I hadn't heard of this before.  I found the zoomable stuff on the canvas page, http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_canvas_4.6/, and had to use Firefox to see it (Chrome didn't work for me).

Comment: @JeanV.Adams unfortunately, I've found that gnuplot cannot handle 10 million points interactively nicely: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/73939/standalone-software-for-plotting-graphs-of-large-amounts-of-data-and-allowing/405613#405613

Answer (score 0):

You could also try [Plotly](https://plot.ly) - it's a web-based interactive graphing app

Comment: Welcome to the site, @ronsolo. At present this is more of a comment than an answer. Would you mind expanding it? What is it about Plotly that makes it a good choice for the OP?

Answer (score -3):

I have launched a software recently www.winplotter.com, which suits the needs you specified.

Comment: Can you explain why this software meets the criteria stated in the question?

Comment: flaggers: it is not forbidden to mention software you're involved with if you clearly identify your association with it (which was done) and if it is actually a suitable answer to the question. The OP needs to do more on that front to explain it's suitability in the context of the question (which things that were asked for does it actually do?) but unless it doesn't relate too the question at all, that just makes it a poor answer rather than spam.